# Stemmed searches

Tags: marklogic, marklogic-10

I am reading Inside MarkLogic Server r7 http://www.odbms.org/wp-content/uploads/2013/11/marklogic-server-r7.pdf, there is one statement regarding stemmed searches which is a bit confusing for me.

*"MarkLogic by default enables the stemmed searches option and leaves word searches
disabled."*

When I checked the default configuration of MarkLogic on my system, **stemmed searches are disabled by default**

So Please clarify which one is true, stemmed searches are by default enabled or disabled?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are reading an old document from 2013. The database defaults have since changed, and in an updated version of that document it states:

> In versions 8 and earlier, MarkLogic by default enables the *stemmed searches* option and leaves *word searches* disabled. Usually that's fine, but it can lead to surprises—e.g., if you're searching for a term in a metadata field where you don't want stemming. For such cases, you can enable the *word searches* index and pass "unstemmed" as an option while constructing the search query constraint. In version 9, the settings are reversed, and MarkLogic by default disables *stemmed searches* and enables *word searches*.

Now, stemming is off by and word search is enabled by default. You can change those settings, if you find that you do need stemming, and instead of database-wide changes, you can decide to [enable stemming on specific fields](https://docs.marklogic.com/admin:database-set-field-stemmed-searches).

[Database Stemming is Off, Word Searches On By Default](https://docs.marklogic.com/guide/relnotes/chap4#id_21809)

> - In MarkLogic 9 and later, when you create a new database, the stemmed searches property is off by default. In MarkLogic 8 and earlier, the default is basic.
> - In MarkLogic 9 and later, when you create a new database, word searches are enabled by default. In MarkLogic 8 and earlier releases, word searches were disabled by default.
> - To achieve the pre-MarkLogic 9 default behavior, configure your database to turn off stemmed searches and set word searches to true.
> - These changes only affect databases you create after upgrading to MarkLogic 9. Databases that exist when you upgrade will retain their previous settings.